# App-release.apk does not contain images

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using rn 0.33 and after the ./android && gradlew assembleRelease I get the app-debug.apk and the app-release.apk.

If I install the debug.apk on my device with the packager I have all the images shown correctly in my app, but within the release.apk all the images are gone.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean the images are gone? Could you show exactly what is the problem with the logs, code and everything?

Answer (score 0):

If it works in debug, but it no longer works in release is likely an issue with ProGuard.

Are these images are gifs?

By default, GIF and WebP are not supported on Android.

You will need to add some optional modules in `android/app/build.gradle`, depending on the needs of your app.

```
dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:0.11.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.11.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:0.11.0'
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:0.11.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:0.11.0'
}
```

Also, if you use GIF with ProGuard, you will need to add this rule in `proguard-rules.pro` :

```
-keep class com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.AnimatedFactoryImpl {
  public AnimatedFactoryImpl(com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.PlatformBitmapFactory, com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ExecutorSupplier);
}
```

[GIF and WebP support on Android.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#gif-and-webp-support-on-android)